# GWT places with Login

Tags: gwt

We need to use GWT places to enable emailing a link to a record in a application we have created.  Our application requires login credentials, so there are two cases we need to handle.

1) you receive a link to a record and you are already logged into the application, in which case clicking the link should take you directly to the record

2) you receive a link to a record and you are *not* already logged into the application, in which case clicking the link should take you to the login screen 1st and then after logging in would take you directly to the record

Has anyone else done something like this?

Best,
maitri

Answer (score 1):

My advice would be to combine the HTML5 History API (`pushState` and `onpopstate`) to keep the place along redirects, using [this technique](https://gist.github.com/1883821) to integrate it with the `PlaceHistoryHandler`, and your containers security to redirect to a login screen (I simply use a `security-constraint` in my `web.xml`).

That way, when you navigate in your app, you have a *permalink* to the place that doesn't use the URL's *hash* part (which is not sent to the server and therefore would be lost when the server redirects to the login page).
When you have such a *permalink* and are not logged in, the servlet container redirects you to the login page, and then back to the URL once logged in. And because that URL didn't use the *hash* part to encode the place, that one has been sent to the server and thus is not lost between redirects.

If you need to support browsers that don't support the HTML5 History API, then you can use as a fallback a button in the app that gives you the permalink. You'd then have to do a redirect from that *permalink* to one that uses the *hash* part to encode the place, i.e. one that can be handled by the `DefaultHistorian`.
This is the approach the new Google Groups (made in GWT) is using.

Comment: Are you sure, that this is the new Google Groups (GWT) approach? For me, it only seems to use a "continue=" GET parameter to construct a URL like https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=groups2&passive=1209600&continue=https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups&followup=https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/google-web-toolkit/-DeTDDUECCE, which is then continued through the POST request on the login screen.

Comment: I was talking about https://groups.google.com/d/topic/google-web-toolkit/-DeTDDUECCE/discussion (click the "Link to this topic" button) vs. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-web-toolkit/-DeTDDUECCE (the actual URL, what you see in your browser's address bar). Google Groups is a bit special as it has anonymous access, so the _redirect_ can be done in JavaScript and preserve the _hash_ part in the URL. I suppose it works slightly differently when accessing private groups (or when using Google Apps)

Comment: Ok, I see what you mean, good point. These links allow to avoid the client side redirect - a direct server side redirect to the login page is faster. A mechanism to handle "#..." links (copied from the address bar) is still required, however: For browsers that support it (http://caniuse.com/#feat=history), the HTML 5 History approach is ideal. For other browsers, it works with the GET parameter.

Comment: _"A mechanism to handle "#..." links (copied from the address bar) is still required, however"_: not if you use the HTML5 History API. IE users would have a _degraded_ experience by loosing the _hash_ part after redirects; they'd just have to copy/paste the URL again to go where they want.

Comment: Depends on the requirements of the project I'd say, but yes, this is absolutely a valid argument!

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to allow users to copy a URL from the browser's address bar, and send it via email. A link could look like

> www.example.org/index.html#sometoken

Such a link takes the recipient to your GWT application, which then decides what to do. I think, it's *usually* not a problem to just serve the full GWT app, even if the user is not authorized at all (GWT can compile to obfuscated JavaScript) <sup>[*]</sup>. The app itself usually doesn't contain secret data - that data is loaded via AJAX.

It is with the AJAX call where the server can detect that the user isn't logged in - and return an appropriate Exception. When receiving the Exception, the client can forward to the login page (`Window.Location.replace(...)`), just re-encoding the token into a GET parameter

> www.example.org/login.html?historytoken=sometoken

On successful login, the server redirects again to "/index.html#sometoken" (`resp.sendRedirect(...)`). It can construct the URL fragment easily because it can read the get parameter "historytoken".

<sup>[*] If you must protect even the obfuscated code from prying eyes, you can map "index.html" to a Servlet, which sends some short JavaScript app (whose only job is to forward to the login page), instead of the full GWT app, if the user is not logged in.</sup>

#### Alternative solution

Another solution (as long as your entire app is served via HTTPS), might be to integrate the login as a dialog into the app without any redirects. But this approach is not always possible (and not always good).